# How to send mail to abc@gmx.com

Tags: php, email

Can't send mail to  `abc@gmx.com` but my php code is working on another email like `abc@gmail.com` and `abc@mailinator.com`.
I don't have solution of this please help me

```
    App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');
    $To='abc@gmx.com'; 
    $email->to($To); 
    $email->from($From);
    $email->subject($Subject);
    $email->emailFormat('html'); 
    $email->attachments($attachment) ;
    $email->template($template);
    $email->layout = 'default';
    var_dump($email->send($message));
    if ($email->send($message))
    { 
        return true;
    } 
   else 
   { 
       return false; 
   }
```

Comment: Without example code and details on what host/OS/PHP-version you're running we can't really help you.

Comment: Are the mails correctly sent but not received? Do you get any bounce-messages on the sender's email? Is the sending IP-address on a blocklist (mxtoolbox.com)?

You could always try to send via a specific SMTP-server, try GMail if you have a GMail-account.

Comment: My code is working on abc@gmail.com

Comment: hosted on aws no smtp use

Comment: do `abc@gmx.com` exists and would you have smtp configured for that.

Comment: i am not using smtp for mail and i am loggedin in octalsoft@gmx.com account please help

Comment: Try dump the whole `$email`, I think there will be an error information somewhere.

Comment: @PoorviSharma please,calm down, and read what we are telling you, and do them, and answer to our comments. otherwise, you cant get a help with only "help me".

Comment: dump return bool(true).Is there any issue about smtp

Answer (score 0):

> Please check this code and check whether you are receiving mail from both the email id's

```
<?php
$to = "abc@gmx.com";
$subject = "Provide your subject matter";
$body = "This is test message!";
$headers = "From: sender@example.com" . "\r\n" .
"CC: abc@gmail.com";
mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers);
?>
```